# Why does moviepy concatenate function not function with list?

Tags: python-3.x, moviepy

I made a code which combines videos and if theyre not there they wont be combined but wheres the problem ? For context im trying to make a script that compiles a video through google searches

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import os
from moviepy.editor import *
from pathlib import Path


def videoedit():
  datafolder = Path("G:\\Projekt\\Projekt\\Clips")
  file_to_open1 = datafolder / "Clip1.mp4"
  file_to_open2 = datafolder / "Clip2.mp4"
  file_to_open3 = datafolder / "Clip3.mp4"
  file_to_open4 = datafolder / "Clip4.mp4"
  file_to_open5 = datafolder / "Clip5.mp4"
  clipA = []
  try:
   clip1 = VideoFileClip(str(file_to_open1))
   clipA = clipA.extend('clip1')
  except:
   print("Clip1 wurde nicht gefunden")
  try:
   clip2 = VideoFileClip(str(file_to_open2))
   clipA = clipA.extend('clip2')
  except:
   print("Clip2 wurde nicht gefunden")
  try:
   clip3 = VideoFileClip(str(file_to_open3))
   clipA = clipA.extend('clip3')
  except:
   print("Clip3 wurde nicht gefunden")
  try: 
   clip4 = VideoFileClip(str(file_to_open4))
   clipA = clipA.extend('clip4')
  except:
   print("Clip4 wurde nicht gefunden")
  try: 
   clip5 = VideoFileClip(str(file_to_open5))
   clipA = clipA.extend('clip5')
  except:
   print("Clip5 wurde nicht gefunden")
  clipA
  final_clip = concatenate_videoclips(clipA)
  final_clip.write_videofile("Compilation.mp4",fps=30)
videoedit()
```

Theres the error message(os windows):

```
Clip2 wurde nicht gefunden (eng: Clip2 not found)
Clip3 wurde nicht gefunden
Clip4 wurde nicht gefunden
Clip5 wurde nicht gefunden
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "youtube_s.py", line 48, in <module>
    videoedit()
  File "youtube_s.py", line 46, in videoedit
    final_clip = concatenate_videoclips(clipA)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\compositing\concatenate.py", line 71, in concatenate_videoclips
    tt = np.cumsum([0] + [c.duration for c in clips])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

But there is a clip2,clip3,clip4,clip5 and the function doesnt work with a list but why

Comment: Does it help if you use `clipA.append(clip1)` and `clipA.append(clip2)` ...(without the quotes around `clip1` and `clip2`...)  instead of `clipA.extend('clip1')` and `clipA.extend('clip2')`

Comment: Clip Append didnt help. But i will Try without the string Mark. But thanks for your quick response

Comment: If `clip1` is a list then definitely you should use like `clip1`,  not `'clip1'`.

Comment: i did try that as shown in the answer below. it doesnt help

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:
with just the ' removed there is the error message:

```
Clip1 wurde nicht gefunden(made up by myself, means :Clip# not found)
Clip2 wurde nicht gefunden
Clip3 wurde nicht gefunden
Clip4 wurde nicht gefunden
Clip5 wurde nicht gefunden
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "youtube_s.py", line 48, in <module>
    videoedit()
  File "youtube_s.py", line 46, in videoedit
    final_clip = concatenate_videoclips(clipA)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\compositing\concatenate.py", line 75, in concatenate_videoclips
    w = max([r[0] for r in sizes])
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

with extend and ' removed or not removed:

```
Clip2 wurde nicht gefunden
Clip3 wurde nicht gefunden
Clip4 wurde nicht gefunden
Clip5 wurde nicht gefunden
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "youtube_s.py", line 48, in <module>
    videoedit()
  File "youtube_s.py", line 46, in videoedit
    final_clip = concatenate_videoclips(clipA)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\compositing\concatenate.py", line 71, in concatenate_videoclips
    tt = np.cumsum([0] + [c.duration for c in clips])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

what could be a clue is that Clip1 is found and didnt have an error.

But honestly i dont know what to do now .

---

**ANSWER**

You have to use clip.append(Clip1), instead of clip = clip.append(Clip1). That will work